# Lyapunov's Stability Theorem Application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m stuck on the following problem:

> Let $g$ be continuous and have continuous first partial derivatives in the domain D containing the origin. Consider the following system and answer the questions below:
>
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = -y + xg(x,y)$$
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dt} = x + yg(x,y)$$
>
> $a$.) Why is there a need for continuous first partial derivatives imposed, or can this requirement be omitted?
>
> $b$.) When is the system asymptotically stable (verify)
>
> $c$.) When is the system unstable  (verify)

In most of the problems I've worked with, I've been given a positive definite function $V(x, y)$ to work with and then I would just check the requirements of the theorem and determine it's stability. This problem is different in that no function is given to work with and there is an added function in the system definitions. Any comments or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a system: $$x'=Ax+h(x)$$
where A is a matrix with eigenvalues with non zero real part (in your case the eigenvalues are 1 and -1) and besides
$$\underset{\|x\|\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\|h(x)\|}{\|x\|}=0$$ then there exists stable manifold.

So now you can imagine what you have to check.

Comment: I think I've figured out part b and c, but I'm not sure about part a. Do you have any suggestions for that part?

Comment: @SamanthaSmith If the system is continuously differentiable then in particular is Lipschitz so there is an unique solution (Picard's theorem). I thing that is the reason. 

But it could be because of other reasons according with what you do in class.